# Wordpress htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to redirect any pages that match a certain criteria to be redirected to another location. So far I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^faq/$ "http\:\/\/staging\.somesite\.domain\.com\/" [R=302,L]
```

but this does not find a match for: http://staging.somesite.domain.com/faq/data/

Can anyone point me in the right direction. Basically I want the redirect to go to the homepage of the site

Regards,
Robert

Comment: So you want anything starting with `faq/` to be redirected to the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...basically your regular expression says "*the query string starts with `faq/` and then there is nothing else*". This is not what you want. Either lose the `$` (which is the symbol for "*end of the string*") or insert `.*` before `$`. And there is no need to escape anything in the target URL as it is not parsed as regular expression.